# Redireccionamiento

Tags: php, redirección

Tengo un sistema alojado en una subcarpeta de `public_html` ejemplo: `public_html/subcarpeta/index.php`
lo que sucede es que cuando hago el `"midominio.com/subcarpeta"` me sale todo el contenido que tengo en mi subcarpeta y lo que quiero es que se redireccione al sistema mas o menos así `"midominio.com/subcarpeta/index.php"` pero no quiero escribir todo esto `"midominio.com/subcarpeta/index.php"` simplemente hacer esto `"midominio.com/subcarpeta"`

Comment: tienes un archivo `index.php` dentro de dicha carpeta?

Answer (score 0):

en la raíz del proyecto es decir en midominio.com/ debes crear un archivo de index.php que te redireccione a midominio.com/subcarpeta/index.php

en ese archivo index.php pones este codigo de redirección

```
header("Location:subcarpeta/index.php");
```

Saludos, espero te sirva.

Comment: pude solucionarlo el problema gracias a sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Si el servidor de *PHP* es *Apache*, crea un archivo (si no existe) de nombre *.htaccess* dentro de *public_html*.

Edita el archivo y escribe:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

La primera línea evita que se muestren todos los archivos dentro del directorio.

La segunda línea fuerza a cargar unos de los archivos en el orden indicado de izquierda a derecha cuando no se especifica el archivo en la url. En caso de no existir ninguno de los archivos relacionados retorna un error **403 Forbidden**.

Quiere decir...

*"midominio.com/subcarpeta/index.php"* carga *index.php* si existe, si no error 403.

*"midominio.com/subcarpeta"* carga *index.php* si existe, si no error 403.

Comment: muchas gracias la verdad que me sirvio de mucho.

Comment: @MarCoDev deberías hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mejor como funciona StackOverflow y si te sirvió aceptar la respuesta y puntuarla si es conveniente.